# Why P(X=x) is not zero here?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function

[image: The CDF of a random variable is given as]
From the CDF,I feel that the random variable here is continuous.So shouldn't the P(X=x) equals 0 here and we only need to find P(X>=1).

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). 
When you retype the question, add the [tag:self-study] tag 
& read [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've 
tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help 
you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: The random variable is not strictly continuous; examine that cumulative distribution function closely, let us say for $x=0$, and you should be able to see that.

Comment: Graph $F$ and look for any vertical jumps.

Comment: Your feelings are not a reliable indicator. Draw the cdf and then look at it.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that $\lim_{x\,\uparrow\,0} F(x)=0$ and $F(0) = \frac14.$

Thus you have a jump at $0.$ The c.d.f. is not continuous at $0.$

Likewise $\lim_{x\,\uparrow\,2} F(x)= \frac34$ and $F(2)=1,$ so there is also a jump at that point. The c.d.f. is not continuous at $2.$